# How to load an initial set of images, then animate between them randomly without jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

On my page I have a gallery (just a `div`) with several images on it.  I want to show the first 9 images immediately, then load more images and use CSS transitions to animate between the existing images.

Loading the initial images is easy but I do not know the best way to load the next set of images and then start animating (using the CSS Transform property).  So far this is what I have:

HTML (abbreviated):

```
<div id="mainContainer">
    <div class="imageHolder"><img class="homeImages" src="test.png"></div>
    <div class="imageHolder"><img class="homeImages" src="test1.png"></div>
    <div class="imageHolder"><img class="homeImages" src="test3.png"></div>
</div>
```

CSS (abbreviated):

```
img {
    display: inline;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 30%;
}

.changed.opaque {
    opacity: 0;
    border: 2px solid red;
}
```

I am looking to do a variety of effects, the most simple one would be to change the opacity and fade one image over the other.  To load the next set of images I have this:

Javascript:

```
    var imageArray = [
        'test2.png',
        'test3.png',
        'test4.png',
        'test5.png',
        'test6.png',
    ];
    var imageNodeArray = [];

    for(var i = imageArray.length - 1; i >= 0; i -= 1) {
        var img = new Image();
        img.onload = function() {
           imageNodeArray.push(this);
        };
        img.src = imageArray[i];
    }
    document.onclick = function() {
        imageNodeArray[0].setAttribute('class', 'changed.opaque');
        divs[0].appendChild(imageNodeArray[0])
    }
```

This does add an image to my `mainContainer` however, even though I can tell from devTools that it has the `changed.opaque` class applied to it, no opacity is shown on the added image.

I am curious about this.  I would also like to know the best way to "stack" images to have a bunch to animate through.  I am not sure that appending child is right.... Thank you

Comment: Have you tried element.classList.toggle(".make-fade"); ?

Comment: I do not have a `.make-fade` class...

Comment: That was just a name I made up. classList.toggle will work with any class.

Comment: If you use classList.contains("myclass"); with classList.toggle("myclass"); you should be able to do what your trying.

Comment: how is that any different than adding a class?

Comment: It will preserve inheritance of class attributes so you don't have to write as much when your code gets bigger.

Comment: By the way in the toggle method it shouldn't have that dot in front of the name. Sorry about that.

Comment: Also it's easier. You could just concat names together, but that's a lot of work.

Comment: A class name shouldn't contain `.` as `.` is the prefix used in CSS. defining `.change.opaque` would tell CSS to target the element with class `change` and `opaque` not `change.opaque`. Try adding a normal class name or if you want to add multiple they should just be separated by spaces.

Comment: Or use `imageNodeArray[0].setAttribute('class', 'changed opaque')` to add 2 classes then your CSS should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function animate() {
    var index = Math.floor((Math.random() * document.querySelectorAll('#mainContainer > .imageHolder').length + 1));
    var current = document.querySelector('.top');
    var next = document.querySelector('.imageHolder:nth-of-type(' + index + ')');
    current.className = "imageHolder";
    next.className += "top";
}
```

Should be able to handle and switch between any dynamically inserted images.

Currently using:

```
.imageHolder {
    display: none;
}
.top {
    display: inherit;
}
```

to switch the image is just a simple implementation.

Here's the working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/e9dxN/1/

Alternative implementation: http://jsfiddle.net/e9dxN/6/

Comment: Any idea how this could be scaled (for a grid of images for example). In that scenario, the float would make the image always go to the upper left...

Comment: @Startec I've reworked the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/e9dxN/4/ to fit your requirements. Instead of just switching the top image, it just replaces the src from a bank of images within the DOM.

Comment: I like this implementation. Why is the `.top {display:inherit}` necessary though?

Comment: @Startec Forgot to remove the unused style after updating the fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/e9dxN/5/ has it removed.